# Time zones and country ISO codes

Tags: data-request, geospatial, csv

I am looking for a simple CSV with the list of country names, country ISO codes, city, time zone UTC and DST... It seems simple, but I am struggling to find it. Any advice/help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Many countries have more than one time zone (Russia has 11) – how would you want the data to handle this? You could use a single time zone for the national capital, or have multiple rows for each country, but this complexity might be one reason you're struggling to find all the information in a single dataset.

Comment: Thanks @MattAshby for your comment... You are right indeed. Actually my request concerns any type of structured data related to time zones. I will update my question to reflect that: country code and city.

Answer (score 1):

There is IANA [tzdb](https://data.iana.org/time-zones/tz-link.html) with a list of all timezones. It's quite complex and changing since timezones change too, for example in Russia timezones changed several times during the last 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

[geonames](http://www.geonames.org) offers this both through their API and bulk dumps.